# Optional parameter with constraint in the middle of Rails route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, constraints

Is it possible to have a constraint on the **optional** route parameter that is **'in the middle'** of the route?

I would like to have a following route:

```
get ':city(/:suburb)/:venue_type', venue_type: /bar|restaurant|cafe/
```

That would show a list of venues of specific type located in the city, or optionally have it narrowed down to suburb. The only `:venue_types` that I support are `bar, restaurant` and `cafe`.

Now I would like to achieve following mappings:

```
/nyc/manhattan/bar -> :city = nyc, :suburb = manhattan, :venue_type = bar
/nyc/bar           -> :city = nyc, :suburb = (nil),     :venue_type = bar
/nyc/whatever/cafe -> :city = nyc, :suburb = whatever,  :venue_type = cafe
/nyc/whatever      -> :city = nyc, :suburb = whatever,  :venue_type = (nil) - routing error
```

So far I've tried with the following which doesn't do the job:

```
class ValidSuburb
  INVALID = %w[bar restaurant cafe]
  def self.matches?(request)
    request.params.has_key?(:suburb) && !INVALID.include?(request.params[:suburb])
  end
end
get ':city(/:suburb)/:venue_type', venue_type: /bar|restaurant|cafe/, suburb: ValidSuburb.new
```

Is this possible to be achieved at all through constraints or do I have to resort in having multiple routes?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing something, but wouldn't it be simpler to just have 2 routes?

```
get ':city/:venue_type', constraints: { venue_type: /bar|restaurant|cafe/ }
get ':city/:suburb/:venue_type', constraints: { venue_type: /bar|restaurant|cafe/ }
```

Here if anything but `"bar"`, `"restaurant"`, or `"cafe"` are passed as that fragment after `/nyc/.../bar`, the first route will be skipped, allowing it to match to the second route.

If `/nyc/whatever` is passed, it won't meet the constraints/format of either route, causing the RouteError you're after.

Comment: Yes this is what I would have to resort to. However I would welcome a constrained based solution as my 'real' route is going over multiple lines with few more parameters and would be convenient not to duplicate it.

Comment: This is why it can be best **not** to water down your issue in certain circumstances.